# iPod touch bad battery performance after updating to iOS 4

Tags: ipod-touch, ios, battery

Hey, I own an iPod touch 2g which worked great until I updated to iOS4. After I did the update, it takes just a few hours for the battery to run out. Even if I´m not doing anything with it. I noticed that if I turn off wifi the battery life is great. So I´m hoping you guys can help me with either a solution to this issue and get it to work normally even with wifi on, or some way to get the wifi turned off when blocking it.

Some things I already try: - fully discharge the vattery and then charge it to 100% - restore the iPod - Updated iOS again to 4.1 now

Thanks in advance!

Comment: iOS 4 is known to cause problems with 2nd gen iPhones and iPod Touches. You're gonna want to [restore it](http://lifehacker.com/5572003/how-to-downgrade-your-iphone-3g[s]-from-ios-4-to-ios-313).

Answer (score 2):

Try to completely disable Push Notifications in the Settings application. This *might* lead to the iPod not trying to maintain a WiFi connection all the time and thus increase battery life.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a combination of the fact that the age of your device means the battery is losing capacity anyway, and the fact that iOS4 is much more resource-intensive. To preserve and keep the battery in good running order, every month or so calibrate it, and make sure the software is always running the newest version, as bug and software fixes can improve battery life. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For others who come across this question:

I had really bad battery life when my ipod was having a hard time connecting to the network at home. It was continually attempting to connect and that was draining the battery. Something to check out.